# Origin of “riff”

Tags: etymology, music

What’s the origin of *[riff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostinato#Riff),* a repeated musical motif? Wikipedia and the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=riff) both state that its origin is uncertain, possibly an alteration of *riffle,* *refrain,* or *rhythmic figure.* Is there any more solid information available on the etymology?

Comment: I don't really know, and I haven't looked it up (that's your job), but as a native American English speaker who uses the term, I can tell you that for me it associates with _riffle_, a word related to _ripple_ semantically and phonetically, and that I associate it also with rapidly moving over the high points of something, like _riffling through a book_ (by flipping the pages rapidly) to catch some high-level identification. The musical use in jazz has been picked up in other arts, where critics talk about `X` _riffing on_ `Y`, usually meaning 'quoting', but not only in music.

Comment: @JohnLawler I agree – and there’s a pretty good discussion of some of that in the references linked from my question, like the bit on other artists “riffing.” I’m just hoping that there might be something more solid in literature or less accessible references.

Comment: @rhetorician Yes, that’s one of the possibilities mentioned in the question. I’m more interested in the evidence backing each of the options and whether any of it is potentially conclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They aren't lying when they say it's uncertain.

Another possibility is that of *riffing*. It's generally considered that the verb *riff* came from the noun *riff*, and the gerund *riffing* from that by the normal *-ing* production, but the gerund *riffing* is in fact found slightly earlier. This though just moves the problem around; we now ask where *riffing* came from, and if it didn't come from *riffing* < *riff*(v) < *riff*(n), then it we've more or less the same possibilities of *refrain*, *ripple*, etc.

To consider how likely they are, let's look at a couple of early uses. The noun form first:

> 1934   Tune Times Aug. 601/1   He runs through the gamut of negro piano riffs.
>
> 1962   J. Baldwin Another Country i. i. 16   They might swap stories of..gigs they'd played, riffs they remembered.

The verb:

> 1935   Atlanta Daily World 5 July 2/1,   I..got one of those mouthpieces I invented which has never been used in this country before. It takes an iron lip and an iron jaw to ‘riff’ through 'em.
>
> 1948   S. Finkelstein Jazz 213   A single instrument..could riff as effectively as, and even more subtly than, a full band or full choir.

The gerund:

> 1933   Pittsburgh Courier 15 July ii. 2/6   They pay to hear..riffing of saxophones.
>
> 1949   L. Feather Inside Be-bop vi. 42   Jo Stafford's arrangement of The Gentleman is a Dope began with four bars of unmistakably bop riffing.
>
> 1958   G. Boatfield in P. Gammond Decca Bk. of Jazz xxiv. 310   These are extraordinary and unique tracks, with Dodds making soaring and at times agonizing music against the sombre riffing of the brassmen.

I've deliberately ignored figurative uses and kept to some of the earlier only.

Now, if we accept that the noun came first, then looking at the first two cases quoted above, it is quite easy to imagine *refrain* being substitute in those two uses without much damage to the sentence. It's not quit right to consider later uses of *riff* as exactly synonymous with *refrain*, but at this point in history, that seems to work okay. So, the theory is that *riff* started out as pretty much just an abbreviation of *refrain* and the went its separate ways.

If however the very or the gerund were actually the first forms, then *riffle* becomes a more likely possibility, though alas that too is a word of unclear origin and perhaps of multiple origins in different senses. *Ripple* is a possible origin of *riffle* in this sense, but not the only one.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the excellent review of the available evidence! The verb/gerund examples are especially interesting, as they imply a somewhat different meaning than the word has now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The suffix on *riffle* is iterative.

There are many examples of this type of derivation in English.  One is *patter* from *pat*.  (It’s defined as *a rapid succession of light taps*.)    Word pairs like *pat/patter* are an established pattern (haha) in English.

In the case of *riff*,the original, non-iterated verb had been lost.  The *riff* invented/innovated by jazz musicians is thus a **back formation.**  It follows the pattern, which must have helped it lexicalize (in other words, catch on.)

It makes sense if you understand a riff as the “hook”, the essence of the refrain, what is being repeated.  I doubt you will be able to pinpoint one source word - the intersection of possible sources adds to its appeal.  The musicians who came up with this were riffing on language, so to speak.

Comment: That seems plausible. Any references you may have would be useful, although I understand that they're often problematic when it comes to jazz jargon.